# Protractor and Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, protractor

How to run Protractor tests on IE?
[15:58:08] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[15:58:08] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[15:58:08] E/launcher - Unable to create new service: InternetExplorerDriverService
[15:58:08] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
npm ERR! Exit status 199

Webdriver is started and running.

```js
var Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');
exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine',
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: ['e2e.js'],

    onPrepare: ()=>{

       var width = 816;
       var height = 480;
       browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(width, height);

      //browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({savePath: 'target/screenshots'}));

    },

    jasmineNodeOpts:{
      showColors: true
    },

    suites:{
      smoke:['smoke.js'],
      regression: ['regression.js'],
      humanity: ['humanity.js']


    },
    capabilities: {
      'browserName': 'internet explorer',
      'ignoreProtectedModeSettings': true
  }
  
  


  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure Protractor (JS) for running tests in Microsoft Edge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47891742/how-to-configure-protractor-js-for-running-tests-in-microsoft-edge)

Comment: @NicoHaase  How to configure Protractor (JS) for running tests in Microsoft Edge? I tried but: E/launcher - unable to create new service: EdgeDriverService.Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-CA1MO0A', ip: '192.168.0.26', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_201'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown /// E/launcher - SessionNotCreatedError: Unable to create new service: EdgeDriverService

Comment: @NicoHaase MicrosoftWebdriver and IEdriverServer 3.141.5 both are present in node module protractor folder webdriver manager

Comment: Perhaps the issue is related to the webdriver manager version, try to refer [this article](https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat/issues/381) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43763548/how-to-run-protractor-tests-in-ie-where-protractor-is-installed-globally?rq=1) to update the webdriver manager version.

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT I cheked article and thread and followed along. IE just opens and stays "frozen".[10:33:19] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[10:33:19] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
Started /// and thats it, no error, no test passed, nothing

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26395216/with-protractor-how-to-setup-internet-explorer-configuration